# A translator class in Python

Tags: python, google-translate

This class can be used to access the Google Translate web interface and get translation result for large text (split up into sentences).

The `Signal` class is copied from [here](http://abstractfactory.io/blog/dynamic-signals-in-pyqt/).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import re
import traceback
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



class Signal:
    def __init__(self):
        """
        :type self: Signal
        :return:
        """
        self.__subscribers = []
        """:type: list of [function]"""
    def emit(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for sub in self.__subscribers:
            sub(*args, **kwargs)
    def connect(self, func):
        self.__subscribers.append(func)
    def disconnect(self, func):
        try:
            self.__subscribers.remove(func)
        except ValueError:
            print("Warning: function %s not removed from signal %s" % (func, self))

# signal = Signal()
# def callback():
#     print("Calling back...")
# signal.connect(callback)
# signal.emit()


class Translator(Signal):
    allowed_lang = ("nl", "fr", "de", "en")
    def __init__(self, from_lang, to_lang, orig_str = None, filename = None):
        """
        A translation class for accessing google translate
        :type self: Translator
        :type from_lang: str
        :type to_lang: str
        :type orig_str: str
        :type filename: str
        :param from_lang:
        :param to_lang:
        :param orig_str:
        :param filename:
        :return:
        """
        super().__init__()
        self.connect(self.report)

        self._from_lang = from_lang
        self._to_lang = to_lang
        self.agent = {'User-Agent': "Mozilla/4.0"}
        self.linkroot = "http://translate.google.com/m?sl=%s&hl=%s&q=" % (self.from_lang, self.to_lang)

        if orig_str != None:
            self.orig_str = str(orig_str)
        elif filename != None:
            with open(filename) as fh:
                self.orig_str = fh.read()
        else:
            raise Exception("You must provide orig_str or filename")

        # Clean up the input string
        # todo: preserve punctuation
        self.orig_str = self.orig_str.replace("\n", "  ").replace("\r", "")
        self.orig_str = re.compile(r"(?<=[.!?;])\s+").split(self.orig_str)
        self.orig_str = [x.strip() for x in self.orig_str]
        self.orig_str = [x for x in self.orig_str if x]
        self.n_sentences = len(self.orig_str)
        self.n_translated = 0

    @property
    def from_lang(self):
        return self._from_lang
    @from_lang.setter
    def from_lang(self, new_lang):
        print("Setting from_lang")
        if new_lang not in self.allowed_lang:
            raise Exception("%s not valid language option" % new_lang)
        self._from_lang = new_lang
    @property
    def to_lang(self):
        return self._to_lang
    @to_lang.setter
    def to_lang(self, new_lang):
        print("Setting to_lang")
        if new_lang not in self.allowed_lang:
            raise Exception("%s not valid language option" % new_lang)
        self._to_lang = new_lang

    def translate_sentence(self, sentence):
        """
        Translate one sentence
        :param sentence:
        :return:
        """
        query = urllib.parse.quote(sentence)
        link = self.linkroot + query
        try:
            request = urllib.request.Request(link, headers=self.agent)
            webpage = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage)
            res = soup.find_all("div", class_="t0")[0].string
        except Exception as e:
            traceback.print_exc()
            res = "Failed to fetch translation from google."
        self.n_translated += 1
        self.emit()
        return res

    def translate(self, n_threads=4):
        """
        Parallelization using multiprocessing
        :return:
        """
        pool = Pool(n_threads)
        self.trans_str = pool.map(self.translate_sentence, self.orig_str)


    def contrast(self):
        return zip(self.orig_str, self.trans_str)

    def report(self):
        print("\rTranslated %d/%d sentences..." % (self.n_translated, self.n_sentences), end="")

    def __str__(self):
        """
        Output a plain text string
        :type self: Translator
        :rtype: str
        :return:
        """
        res = ""
        for i, o in self.contrast():
            res += i + "\n" + o + "\n\n"
        return res

    def prettify(self):
        """
        Output an html string
        :type self: Translator
        :rtype: str
        :return:
        """
        # import pdb
        # pdb.set_trace()
        res = ""
        for i, o in self.contrast():
            res += "<div>\n<p>\n" + i + "\n</p>\n<p>\n<i>\n" + o + "\n</i></p>\n</div>\n\n"
        return res


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mystring = """
    Dat maakt het Openbaar Ministerie (OM) in Amsterdam bekend?
    De 56-jarige Holleeder wordt verdacht van het medeplegen van moord en deelneming aan een criminele organisatie. Hij wordt waarschijnlijk begin komende week voorgeleid!
    Zijn arrestatie volgt op onderzoek dat is gedaan naar de verklaringen van de nieuwe kroongetuige, Fred Ros in het omvangrijke Passageproces over de liquidaties. "Hij heeft belastend over Holleeder verklaard", aldus een woordvoerster van het OM.
    """
    trans = Translator(from_lang="nl", to_lang="en", orig_str=mystring)
    trans.translate()
    print(trans)
```

A new version of this class is available here: [A translator class in Python v2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/73556/a-translator-class-in-python-v2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### PEP8

Please follow [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the official style guide of Python.

In parameter lists, don't put spaces around `=` like this:

> ```
> def __init__(self, from_lang, to_lang, orig_str = None, filename = None):
> ```

Write like this:

```
def __init__(self, from_lang, to_lang, orig_str=None, filename=None):
```

---

Put one blank line before method definitions inside a class.
Instead of this:

> ```
> class Translator(Signal):
>     allowed_lang = ("nl", "fr", "de", "en")    
>     def __init__(self, from_lang, to_lang, orig_str=None, filename=None):
> ```

Write like this:

```
class Translator(Signal):
    allowed_lang = ("nl", "fr", "de", "en")    

    def __init__(self, from_lang, to_lang, orig_str=None, filename=None):
```

---

Don't use `!=` or `==` when comparing with `None` like this:

> ```
>     if filename != None:
> ```

Write like this:

```
    if filename is not None:
```

Actually, since `filename` is supposed to be a string,
this would be the most natural way to write this condition:

```
    if filename:
```

---

Avoid using bare `except` clauses like this as much as possible:

> ```
>     except:
>         res = "Failed to fetch translation from google."
> ```

This is somewhat better:

```
    except Exception:
        res = "Failed to fetch translation from google."
```

But it's best to use as specific exception type as possible.

---

In this code:

> ```
> def translate(self):
>     """
>     Parallelization using multiprocessing
>     :return:
>     """
>     pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
>     self.trans_str = pool.map(self.translate_sentence, self.orig_str)
> ```

It's not recommended to define attributes outside of `__init__`.
It would be better to initialize the value in the constructor.

---

It's strange that the docstring says:

> ```
>     :type orig_str: str
> ```

But then you have this logic:

> ```
>     if orig_str is not None:
>         self.orig_str = str(orig_str)
> ```

If the parameter is supposed to be a string,
then you can simply do this:

```
    if orig_str:
        self.orig_str = orig_str
```