# A translator class in Python v2

Tags: python, google-translate

Version 2 of [A translator class in Python](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/73548/a-translator-class-in-python/73550)

Changes:

- Style compliant to PEP8
- Both `orig_str` and `filename` allowed to be any object with `__str__` method
- Improved type annotation

Multiprocessing is used to increase performance.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import re
import traceback
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



class Signal:
    """
    :type __subscribers: list of [function]
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.__subscribers = []
        """:type: list of [function]"""

    def emit(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for sub in self.__subscribers:
            sub(*args, **kwargs)

    def connect(self, func:function):
        self.__subscribers.append(func)

    def disconnect(self, func:function):
        try:
            self.__subscribers.remove(func)
        except ValueError:
            print("Warning: function %s not removed from signal %s" % (func, self))

# signal = Signal()
# def callback():
#     print("Calling back...")
# signal.connect(callback)
# signal.emit()


class Translator(Signal):
    """
    :type allowed_lang: tuple
    :type _from_lang: str
    :type _to_lang: str
    :type trans_str: list of [str]
    :type agent: dict of [str, str]
    :type linkroot: str
    :type n_sentences: int
    :type n_translated: int
    """
    allowed_lang = ("nl", "fr", "de", "en")

    def __init__(self, from_lang:str, to_lang:str, orig_str:object=None, filename:object=None):
        """
        A translation class for accessing google translate
        :param Translator self:
        :param str from_lang:
        :param str to_lang:
        :param str object:
        :param str filename:
        :return:
        """
        super().__init__()
        self.connect(self.report)

        self._from_lang = from_lang
        self._to_lang = to_lang
        self.trans_str = []
        self.agent = {'User-Agent': "Mozilla/4.0"}
        self.linkroot = "http://translate.google.com/m?sl=%s&hl=%s&q=" % (self.from_lang, self.to_lang)

        if orig_str is not None:
            self.orig_str = str(orig_str)
        elif filename is not None:
            with open(str(filename)) as fh:
                self.orig_str = fh.read()
        else:
            raise Exception("You must provide orig_str or filename")

        # Clean up the input string
        self.orig_str = self.orig_str.replace("\n", "  ").replace("\r", "")
        self.orig_str = re.compile(r"(?<=[.!?;])\s+").split(self.orig_str)
        self.orig_str = [x.strip() for x in self.orig_str]
        self.orig_str = [x for x in self.orig_str if x]
        self.n_sentences = len(self.orig_str)
        self.n_translated = 0

    @property
    def from_lang(self) -> str:
        return self._from_lang

    @from_lang.setter
    def from_lang(self, new_lang:str):
        print("Setting from_lang")
        if new_lang not in self.allowed_lang:
            raise Exception("%s not valid language option" % new_lang)
        self._from_lang = new_lang

    @property
    def to_lang(self) -> str:
        return self._to_lang

    @to_lang.setter
    def to_lang(self, new_lang:str):
        print("Setting to_lang")
        if new_lang not in self.allowed_lang:
            raise Exception("%s not valid language option" % new_lang)
        self._to_lang = new_lang

    def translate_sentence(self, sentence:str) -> str:
        """
        Translate one sentence
        :type self: Translator
        """
        query = urllib.parse.quote(sentence)
        link = self.linkroot + query
        try:
            request = urllib.request.Request(link, headers=self.agent)
            webpage = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage)
            res = soup.find_all("div", class_="t0")[0].string
        except Exception as e:
            traceback.print_exc()
            res = "Failed to fetch translation from google."
        self.n_translated += 1
        self.emit()
        return res

    def translate(self, n_threads:int=4):
        """
        Parallelization using multiprocessing
        :type self: Translator
        """
        pool = Pool(n_threads)
        self.trans_str = pool.map(self.translate_sentence, self.orig_str)

    def contrast(self) -> zip:
        return zip(self.orig_str, self.trans_str)

    def report(self):
        print("\rTranslated %d/%d sentences..." % (self.n_translated, self.n_sentences), end="")
        # print a newline at the end
        if self.n_translated == self.n_sentences:
            print()

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        """
        Output a plain text string
        :type self: Translator
        """
        res = ""
        for i, o in self.contrast():
            res += i + "\n" + o + "\n\n"
        return res

    def prettify(self) -> str:
        """
        Output an html string
        :type self: Translator
        """
        # import pdb
        # pdb.set_trace()
        res = ""
        for i, o in self.contrast():
            res += "<div>\n<p>\n" + i + "\n</p>\n<p>\n<i>\n" + o + "\n</i></p>\n</div>\n\n"
        return res


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mystring = """
    Dat maakt het Openbaar Ministerie (OM) in Amsterdam bekend?
    De 56-jarige Holleeder wordt verdacht van het medeplegen van moord en deelneming aan een criminele organisatie. Hij wordt waarschijnlijk begin komende week voorgeleid!
    Zijn arrestatie volgt op onderzoek dat is gedaan naar de verklaringen van de nieuwe kroongetuige, Fred Ros in het omvangrijke Passageproces over de liquidaties. "Hij heeft belastend over Holleeder verklaard", aldus een woordvoerster van het OM.
    """
    trans = Translator(from_lang="nl", to_lang="en", orig_str=mystring)
    trans.translate()
    print(trans)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- It is odd for `Translator` to be a subclass of `Signal`. Normally inheritance models an is-a relationship. Here the translator just wants to emit a signal after translating each sentence. It would be natural to use an attribute for that:

  ```
  self.sentence_translated = Signal()
  ```
- The two setters validate their argument, but `__init__` bypasses that by assigning directly to the underlying attribute. It should assign to the property instead, to benefit from the validation.
- The bunch of lines that performs the task `# Clean up the input string` should be extracted into a function.

Comment: Cool. How do you do the assignment using the property in __init__? I thought python would automatically do it for me.

Comment: @qed Just remove the underscore: `self.from_lang = from_lang` instead of `self._from_lang = from_lang`